Simple question about commutator
$$[H,x]=-\frac{i\hbar}{m} p$$
For a generic energy eigenstate $|\psi\rangle$:
$$\langle\psi|Hx-xH|\psi〉= (E-E)\langle\psi|x|\psi〉= -\frac{i\hbar}{m}\langle\psi|p|\psi\rangle$$
which impies $\langle\psi|p|\psi\rangle=0$. This is an obvious contradiction when consider the free particle Hamiltonian. What is the wrong statement here?

The apparent contradiction arises because $ = 0$ does not imply the particle has zero momentum; it only means the average momentum over the wave function is zero. This is entirely consistent with the free particle Hamiltonian and its eigenstates.

@Lawerence What do you mean? Naively choosing $\psi$ as an eigenstate of $H$ (free particle) would give $\langle \psi, P\psi\rangle=p$, i.e. an eigenvalue. The OP is correct in this sense.

This question is similar to: Expectation of momentum in the bound state. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. See also the linked and related questions therein.
